# Maximum Stock (greedy method)

Tags: java

In a stock market, there is a product with its infinite stocks. The stock prices are given for n  days, where arr[i] denotes the price of the stock on the ith day. There is a rule that a customer can buy at most i stock on the ith  day. If the customer has an amount of k dollars initially, find out the maximum number of stocks they can buy?  For example, for 3 days the price of a stock is given as 7$,10$,4$ . You can buy 1 stock worth 7$ on 1st day , 2 stocks worth 10$  each on day 2 and 3 stocks worth 4$ each on day 3 . If k=100$, you can buy all the stocks (total 6) for 39$

**Constraints**

1.1<=n<=10^5
  2.1<=arr[i]<=100
  3.1<=k<=10^12
**Output Format**

Print the maximum number of stock that a customer can buy.

**Sample Input 0**

3
10 7 19
45

**Sample Output 0**
    4
**Explanation 0**

The customer can purchase 1 stock on day 1,2  stock on day 2 and 1 stock on day 3  for 10$ ,7x2=14$ and 19$ respectively. Hence, total amount is 10+14+19=43  and number of stocks purchased is 4 .

My solution is working only for testcases 0(thats given in example is working) ,7 and 9 in java

**NOT WORKING TEST CASE**
**INPUT:-**
100
26 94 80 59 32 3 38 91 93 33 78 4 79 98 58 60 20 57 34 33 62 79 3 69 63 22 12 14 35 6 61 74 39 75 31 72 28 70 28 94 78 62 57 29 17 92 1 12 64 27 31 17 97 74 29 27 57 74 97 38 9 80 31 83 62 53 84 91 92 39 20 45 64 27 39 56 76 20 46 63 85 3 66 54 57 91 12 68 98 72 78 48 95 17 33 87 11 68 82 53 
167121
**EXPECTED OUTPUT:-**
3868

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

static long buyMaximumProducts(int n, long k, long[] a) {
    // Complete this function
      long numofstocks=0;
      long s=0;
      long quotient=0;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if (k>=a[i])  //still can buy at least one
    {   
        if ((k%a[i])>=(i+1))
        {
            numofstocks= numofstocks+i+1;
            quotient=i+1;
        }
        else
        {   
           if(k/a[i]==0)
           {
               numofstocks++;
               quotient=1;
           }
            else if(k%a[i]!=0)
            {
                numofstocks=numofstocks+(k/a[i]);
                quotient=k/a[i];
            }
            else
            {
                numofstocks=numofstocks+i+1;
                quotient=i+1;
            }
         }

    }

    k=k-(a[i]*quotient);
  }
    return numofstocks;
 }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    long[] arr = new long[n];
    for(int arr_i = 0; arr_i < n; arr_i++){
        arr[arr_i] = in.nextLong();
    }
    long k = in.nextLong();
    long result = buyMaximumProducts(n, k, arr);
    System.out.println(result);
    in.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Consifering you know "future" prices  you need to sort the stocks and buy cheapest first

**EDIT**
You know the prices and quantity of all the stocks and you don't have to buy them sequentially. It's like walking in the store with 20$ in hand and a goal to buy as many beers as possible. There are 1 for 7$ ea, 2 for 8$ ea, 3 for 3$ ea and 4 for 1$ ea (Let's say that all the beers are identical). Under no circumstances it would be wise to choose more expensive bottle instead of cheaper one, so you start buying from the cheapest.

Let's apply that to our problem. Given input

```
4
7 8 3 1
20
```

We have array of stocks

```
{7, 8, 8, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

Your solution would buy 1 for 7$, 1 for 8$ and it would stop there, because it could not afford second 8$ stock.
BUT what happens if we sort that array?
The result would be

```
{1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 8, 8}
```

Now we can greedily buy them! 8 stocks for a total of 20$ instead of 2 for 15$.   The algorithm is simple: if you can afford the next stock - you buy it and increment a counter. If not - you print the counter.

***Code Stuff***

```
import java.util.Arrays; //contains sort function

public class StockBuyer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // here you should parse the input, i'll leave it to you and
        // use values from above example
        int arr[] = {7, 8, 8, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1};
        int moneytospend = 20;
        int bought = 0;

        // sorting array
        Arrays.sort(arr);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length && moneytospend >= arr[i]; i++) {
            moneytospend -= arr[i];
            bought++;
        }
        System.out.println(bought);
    }
}
```

***Summary***

D M already showed you your coding mistakes and I hope that I managed to explain to you why your algorithm was wrong.
Just FYI: There are smarter (and in result faster!) ways to prepare your data before sorting. E.g. you could sort an array of pairs {value, quantity} - and I'll leave it here for you to figure out the rest ;) Happy coding!

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your problem please mark is as accepted by clicking the tick to the left of it. It will make it easier for the community to browse Unanswered page

Answer (score 0):

Your logic in `buyMaximumProducts` is way off.  It's wrong even as a try that doesn't get the optimal solution.

Your `if` statements seem to have the most problems.  For example:

```
if ((k%a[i])>=(i+1))
```

Using the modulus operator here makes no sense.  This is going to give you meaningless results; in some cases the result is that it's going to buy stock when you don't even have enough money to do so.  Let's change the `%` to a `/`.

```
if(k/a[i]==0)
```

This is never going to be true.  We already know that `k >= a[i]` because we're in that `if` statement, so this can't possibly be 0.  If it WAS somehow 0, it would mean that you don't have enough money to buy a share.

```
else if(k%a[i]!=0)
```

You're using the modulus operator again, which still makes no sense.  Use division.

Or better yet, don't even use division.  The entire condition is unnecessary.  We already know (after fixing that first bit of code) that `k/a[i]` is less than `i+1`, meaning we can buy as many shares as we like until we run out of money.  So we can just use `numofstocks = numofstocks + (k / a[i]); quotient=k/a[i];` in the `else` block.

So the `if` logic simplifies to this:

```
    if (k >= a[i])  //still can buy at least one
    {   
        if ((k / a[i]) >= (i+1))
        {
            numofstocks = numofstocks + i + 1;
            quotient=i+1;
        }
        else
        {
            numofstocks = numofstocks + (k / a[i]);
            quotient=k/a[i];
        }
    }
```

But wait, there's another bug.  If the condition `if (k>=a[i])` is false, then that means you didn't have enough money to buy a stock.  But the line `k=k-(a[i]*quotient);` still gets executed, making the algorithm think it's spending money even if nothing is bought.  So you can either bring `k=k-(a[i]*quotient);` inside the `if` statement, or include an `else` statement that sets `quotient` to 0 instead of leaving it at whatever value it previously had.

Of course, once you've done all that, it's *still* not correct.  It's going to spend all the money it can as fast as it can, which is not optimal.  It needs to do the cheapest days first.

Answer (score 0):

The most important part of the the code is using the sorted function.

```
#!/bin/python
import sys

def buyMaximumProducts(n, k, a):
    # Complete this function
    stocks = sorted(enumerate(a, start=1), key=lambda arr: arr[1])
    maxStock = 0
    for stock in stocks:
        count, _ = divmod(k, stock[1])
        if count > 0:
            if count >= stock[0]:
                count = stock[0]
            maxStock += count
            k -= stock[1] * count
        else:
            return maxStock
    return maxStock

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(raw_input().strip())
    arr = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
    k = long(raw_input().strip())
    result = buyMaximumProducts(n, k, arr)
    print result
```